# What do you use to make tzatziki? Onions, garlic, or both?

Tags: onions, garlic, greek-cuisine, tzatziki

I found tzatziki sauce in a supermarket. If I recall correctly, the ingredients listed on the package included onions. I then read on Internet that tzatziki sauce is made with garlic.

What do you use to make tzatziki, onions, garlic, or both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically garlic is used.  If you prefer onions and garlic, go ahead but it's typically cucumber, yogurt, dill, garlic, lemon juice or vinegar, olive oil, salt, pepper, and sometimes sour cream.

Comment: Also one may want to drain the yogurt first to make the sauce a little thicker (well potentially a lot thicker).

Comment: or just use the greek style yogurt if you lack the cheese cloth to drain it yourself.

Comment: Can pour a whole tub of yogurt in a large coffee filter inside a funnel too.  Let drain overnight and you're good to go.  Oh, and you MUST squeeze all the water out of the cucumbers too.